# Company A is an e-commerce store selling rugs online

Tags: custom-attributes, magento2.4.6, custom-prices, patch-data, custom-extension

- Company A is an e-commerce store selling rugs online. Company A wants to charge based on the size of rugs provided by the customer.
- In backend, show product-wise option to enable/disable this functionality and field to specify price per sq. meter.
- Show form on product page to enter height and width in meter. Calculate product price based on below formula and set it as final price while product add to cart.

=> Formula:

```
Final Price = Product Price + (height * width) * Price per sq. meter
```